# Insert data from session array to prestashop database using php

Tags: php, sql, prestashop

Im working on a custom prestashop module that retrieves data from another database(an external database) and  then it inserts the data to the prestashop data base. I've made a php file that retrieves data from the external database and saves to a session variable.

I've got this array from that php file: 
`[0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [productid] => 1
            [1] => 0
            [parent] => 0
            [2] => 0 
            [3] => iPod Shuffle
            [prodname] => iPod Shuffle`
And this is the its code: `FILE) . "/settings.inc.php");

```
//database 1
//$data = array();

$conn = @mysql_connect($GLOBALS['VCS_CFG']["dbServer"],$GLOBALS['VCS_CFG']["dbUser"], $GLOBALS['VCS_CFG']["dbPass"]);
if ($conn){
    if (mysql_select_db($GLOBALS['VCS_CFG']["dbDatabase"])) {
        $SQL = "SELECT * FROM vc_products";
        $q = mysql_query($SQL);

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($q))
        {
            $json_output[] = $row;
            $_SESSION['myData'] = $json_output;
        }
        //echo json_encode($json_output);
        print_r($_SESSION['myData']);
    }
    mysql_close($conn);
}
```

`

im trying to insert the row prodname at the product_name row of the table  ps_order_detail table. Now im making the prestashop module that it will insert that data to Prestashop database. Here is my code:

This is my module's code for the data insert:

```
<?php
if (!defined('_PS_VERSION_'))
    exit;

include 'test.php';

class PrestaBridge extends Module
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->name = 'PrestaBridge';
        $this->tab = 'Front';
        $this->version = 1.5;
        $this->author = 'Sergio Kagiema';
        $this->need_instance = 0;

        parent::__construct();

        $this->displayName = $this->l('PrestaBridge');
        $this->description = $this->l('A module for transferring data from Vcart to Prestashop!');
        $this->confirmUninstall = $this->l('Are you sure you want to uninstall?');

        if (!Configuration::get('PrestaBridge'))      
            $this->warning = $this->l('No name provided');

    } 


    //INSTALL TOY MODULE
    public function install()
    {
        $parent_tab = new Tab();
        foreach (Language::getLanguages(true) as $lang)
            $parent_tab->name [$lang['id_lang']] = 'PrestaBridge';
        $parent_tab->class_name = 'BridgePage';
        $parent_tab->id_parent = 0;
        $parent_tab->module = $this->name;
        $parent_tab->add();
        if (!parent::install()
            || !$this->installModuleTab('BridgePage', array((int)(Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT'))=>'PrestaBridge'), $parent_tab->id)
        )
            return false;
        return true;
    }



    //UNISTALL TOY MODULE
    public function uninstall()
    {
        if (!parent::uninstall()
            || !$this->uninstallModuleTab('BridgePage')
        )
            return false;
        return true;
    }   

    private function installModuleTab($tabClass, $tabName, $idTabParent)
    {
        $idTab = Tab::getIdFromClassName($idTabParent);       
        $idTab = $idTabParent;
        $pass = true ;
        @copy(_PS_MODULE_DIR_.$this->name.'/logo.gif', _PS_IMG_DIR_.'t/'.$tabClass.'.gif');
        $tab = new Tab();
        $tab->name = $tabName;
        $tab->class_name = $tabClass;
        $tab->module = $this->name;
        $tab->id_parent = $idTab;
        $pass = $tab->save();
        return($pass);
    }


    private function uninstallModuleTab($tabClass)
    {
        $pass = true ;
        @unlink(_PS_IMG_DIR_.'t/'.$tabClass.'.gif');
        $idTab = Tab::getIdFromClassName($tabClass);
        if($idTab != 0)
        {
            $tab = new Tab($idTab);
            $pass = $tab->delete();
        }
        return($pass);
    }                                                                                




    public function getContent() {
        $this->_html = '<h2>'.$this->displayName.'</h2>';

        if (Tools::isSubmit('submit')) {
            $sql = 'INSERT INTO '._DB_PREFIX_.'order_detail(product_id, product_name) VALUES';
            $valuesArr = array();
            if  ($data = Db::getInstance()->Execute($sql))
                foreach ($data as $row){
                    $product_id = (int) $row['productid'];
                    $product_name = $row['prodname']; 

                    $valuesArr[] = "('$product_id', '$product_name')";
            }
             $sql .= implode(',', $valuesArr);

            $this->_displayForm();
            return $this->_html;
        }
    } 


    private function _displayForm() {

        $this->_html .= '<div class="clear"></div>';

        $this->_html .= '<div class="bridge" id="bridge">';
        $this->_html .= '<form method="post" action="'.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].'" id="test">';
        $this->_html .= '<input type="text" name="username" id="username"/>';
        $this->_html .= '<input type="text" name="password" id="password"/>';
        $this->_html .= '<button id="myButton" onclick="myfunc()" type="submit">Transfer Data</button>';
        $this->_html .= '</div>';
    }



}
```

?>

Can you help me out please?

Comment: what version are we talking about ? where are you trying to connect ? Module ? In prestashop there is a strict way to add/select/update/delete from databases. Please answer to my questions and I will help you

Comment: it's about Prestashop 1.5. I'm making a module that inserts data to Prestashop's database. So, I'm trying to connect to my database with ftp.

Answer (score 0):

You should start with this http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/DB+class+best+practices

Tells you everything you need to know about best practices. Anyways let's say you are creating a module. It means you are extending a Module class and your module starts like this

```
class yourCustomeModuleName extends Module
    {
    }
```

Between those tags you insert all the relevant data like public __construct function and all the other functions you need, including the hook functions that you want to display your data.

To insert something in to database through Prestashop you need to use execute() command what is a global variable in Prestashop. Here is a example from the link that I provided you with

```
$sql = 'DELETE FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'product WHERE active = 0';
if (!Db::getInstance()->execute($sql))
die('Error etc.)';
```

So that means - you don't need to execute database connections when you are already inside of a class. If this is new to you then I suggest you to read about OOP (object oriented programming)